# How to get the width and height of JQuery UI draggable() object when using cursorAt

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on implementing JQuery UI Draggable() object and added the cursorAt() object.  THen I noticed I need to center the draggable object but don't see how.  I can set the top and left to 0 but I want to center the box (draggable object).  So how to get the draggable object's width and height?

```
$('#gridColumn1').draggable({
    appendTo: 'body', 
    helper: 'clone', 
    start: function(e, ui) { ui.helper.addClass("dragEffect"); }, 
    //cursorAt: { top: 0, left: 0 }
    cursorAt: top: Math.floor(??? / 2), left: Math.floor(??? / 2)
});
```

Comment: Can you add a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) code example?

Comment: I don't have an account at jsfiddle.net.  The draggable object should be able to know the width and height of the draggable object cuz it have a copy of it when dragging.  I just couldn't figure out what to use within the draggable object.

Comment: You don't need an account, just add in your code and click save, it will give you a one-time URL

Comment: What do you mean "center the draggable object"? When you start dragging, it should be centered on the mouse position?

Comment: Yea, the mouse cursor be horizontally centered and vertically centered on the draggable column box.  Something like this "cursorAt: top: Math.floor(??? / 2), left: Math.floor(??? / 2)".  The ??? is the column box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can get get this to is to set the cursor offset at initialization time, which relies on all the draggable type being the same. It doesn't appear as though `cursorAt` accepts a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/kFjJY/2/

```
var $dragitem = $("#gridColumn1");
$dragitem.draggable({
    appendTo: 'body', 
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) { ui.helper.addClass("dragEffect"); }, 
    cursorAt: { top: $dragitem.height()/2, left: $dragitem.width()/2 }
});
```

One issue I noticed, when using an ID selector like you have (`#gridColumn1`) the clone loses it's styling, so make sure you are styling using class selector and not id.

Comment: Yea, it would be nice if cursorAt would accept a function.  I'll accept your answer cuz it works better than none at all.  At least we're making progress.